# Xepersian package: persian vs arabic numerals for sectioning headers

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, arabic, xepersian

I am using `xepersian` as a main package for my thesis in Arabic languge, i had the problem of bibliography with LTR and RTL references in `polyglossia`, I want to make Arabic numerals as a main numbering in `xepersian` if it is possible.

This is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true,colorlinks,citecolor=blue,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}%
\usepackage[nonamebreak]{natbib}
\usepackage[top=30mm, bottom=30mm, left=30mm, right=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1 ]{XB Zar}%Ligatures=TeX, Mapping={} are useless in this case
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{\lr{chapter one}}
\section{\lr{section one}}
\subsection{\lr{subsection one}}
\end{document}
```

here is code update

```
    \begin{filecontents}{SomeReferences.bib}
@article{Baker02limits,
author = {Baker,, Simon and Kanade,, Takeo},
title = {Limits on Super-Resolution and How to Break Them},
journal = {IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell.},
volume = {24},
number = {9},
year = {2002},
issn = {0162-8828},
pages = {1167--1183},
publisher = {IEEE Computer Society},
address = {Washington, DC, USA}
}
@CONFERENCE{Amintoosi87afzayesh,
AUTHOR =       {امین‌طوسی,محمود and مزینی,ناصر and  فتحی,محمود},
TITLE =        {افزایش وضوح ناحیه‌ای},
BOOKTITLE =    {چهاردهمین کنفرانس ملی سالانه انجمن کامپیوتر ایران},
YEAR =         {1387},
ORGANIZATION = {دانشگاه امیرکبیر},
ADDRESS =      {تهران ایران},
month =          {اسفند},
pages = {101--108},
LANGUAGE =     {Persian}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true,colorlinks,citecolor=blue,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}%
\usepackage[nonamebreak]{natbib}
\usepackage[top=30mm, bottom=30mm, left=30mm, right=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1, Ligatures=TeX]{XB Zar}
\begin{document}
\Latincite{Baker02limits}\\
\citep{Amintoosi87afzayesh}\\ 
\bibliographystyle{asa-fa}
\bibliography{SomeReferences}
\end{document}
```

P.s
The complete example is downloadable from this link:[.zip file contains also .bst file](https://pkamc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user4654_myoffice365_site/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=12d3db6256b7e4fef96694e3707bb5d13&authkey=AYmuw76WdB_PqDBGzK72hCE&e=6fef4208bbb24c05982f37f8f603ed49)

[image: legatures effects]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Ligatures=TeX, Mapping={}` as `\settextfont`'s options as you mentioned, there is no issue in my PC. Maybe your `xepersian` package is obsolete.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1, Ligatures=TeX, Mapping={}]{XB Zar}
\begin{document}
\chapter{\lr{chapter one}}
\section{\lr{section one}}
\subsection{\lr{subsection one}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S.

1- The latest versions of `xepersian` and `bidi` are `2017/12/24 v19.8` and `2017/12/05 v31.7`, respectively.
2- `xepersian` package relies on `bidi`.

---

New Edition (and the correct one).

The following solution inspired by `xepersian`'s solution to making persian digit map for text.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mydigits.map}
LHSName "MyDigits"
RHSName "ArabicDigits"

pass(Unicode)

U+002C <> U+060C ; comma ­> arabic comma
U+003F <> U+061F ; question mark -> arabic qm
U+003B <> U+061B ; semicolon -> arabic semicolon

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D <> U+2013 ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D <> U+2014 ; --- -> em dash

U+0027 <> U+2019 ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027 <> U+201D ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022  > U+201D ; " -> right double quote

U+0060 <> U+2018 ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060 <> U+201C ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060 <> U+00A1 ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060 <> U+00BF ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C <> U+201E ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C <> U+00AB ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E <> U+00BB ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET
;;
;; End of file `mydigits.map'.
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{teckit_compile mydigits.map -o mydigits.tec}

\begin{filecontents}{SomeReferences.bib}
@article{Baker02limits,
author = {Baker,, Simon and Kanade,, Takeo},
title = {Limits on Super-Resolution and How to Break Them},
journal = {IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell.},
volume = {24},
number = {9},
year = {2002},
issn = {0162-8828},
pages = {1167--1183},
publisher = {IEEE Computer Society},
address = {Washington, DC, USA}
}
@CONFERENCE{Amintoosi87afzayesh,
AUTHOR =       {امین‌طوسی,محمود and مزینی,ناصر and  فتحی,محمود},
TITLE =        {افزایش وضوح ناحیه‌ای},
BOOKTITLE =    {چهاردهمین کنفرانس ملی سالانه انجمن کامپیوتر ایران},
YEAR =         {1387},
ORGANIZATION = {دانشگاه امیرکبیر},
ADDRESS =      {تهران ایران},
month =          {اسفند},
pages = {101--108},
LANGUAGE =     {Persian}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true,colorlinks,citecolor=blue,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}%
\usepackage[nonamebreak]{natbib}
\usepackage[top=30mm, bottom=30mm, left=30mm, right=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1, Mapping=mydigits,]{XB Zar}
\begin{document}
\Latincite{Baker02limits}\\
\citep{Amintoosi87afzayesh}\\ 
\bibliographystyle{asa-fa}
\bibliography{SomeReferences}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you noticed you can create a file named `mydigits.map`, and then you must compile it with this command:

```
teckit_compile mydigits.map -o mydigits.tec
```

Therefore you can use the font as usual except that you've to set `Mapping` to `mydigits` for making desired adaption.

Comment: With these two commands i have a problem in the bibliography, it shows an Latin comma (,) instead of Arabic Comma (،). code was updated

Comment: @AbdoElfengour
Please see the new edition of the answer.

Comment: you have done a great job @javadr, thanks. Please there is another question here [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408871/multibib-doesnt-work-with-xepersian-package] see what wrong with it.