# Multibib doesn't work with Xepersian package

Tags: natbib, multibib, xepersian

I try to use Multibib package in Xepersian, but does't work, this is my MWE:

```
    \RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyReferences.bib}
@MASTERSTHESIS{Khalighi07MscThesis,
AUTHOR =       {Vafa Khalighi},
AUTHORFA = {خلیقی,وفا},
TITLE =        {Category Theory},
SCHOOL =       {Sydny Univ.},
YEAR =         {2007},
MONTH =        {April}
}
@CONFERENCE{Amintoosi87afzayesh,
AUTHOR =       {امین ‌طوسی محمود and مزینی,ناصر and  فتحی محمود},
TITLE =        {افزایش وضوح ناحیه‌ای},
BOOKTITLE =    {چهاردهمین کنفرانس ملی سالانه انجمن کامپیوتر ایران},
YEAR =         {1387},
ORGANIZATION = {دانشگاه امیرکبیر},
ADDRESS =      {تهران ایران},
month =          {اسفند},
pages = {101--108},
LANGUAGE =     {Persian}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}%[resetlabels,labeled]
\newcites{pr}{مراجع فارسي}
\newcites{en}{مراجع انگلیسی}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.5]{XB Zar}%{XB Niloofar}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.5]{Linux Libertine}
%\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{XB Zar}
\defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1.5]{XB Kayhan Sayeh}
\settextdigitfont[Scale=1.5, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
%
\begin{document}
\citepr{Amintoosi87afzayesh}
\citeen{Khalighi07MscThesis}
%
%\section{Bibliography}
\bibliographystylepr{asa-fa}%apalike
\bibliographypr{MyReferences}
% 
\bibliographystyleen{asa-fa}%apalike
\bibliographyen{MyReferences}
\end{document}
```

or you can download the full directory including `asa-fa.bst` file from here:[MWE full directory](https://pkamc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user4654_myoffice365_site/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=1cf81d916e3de435eb3e979ac004334fb&authkey=AZoW2Euz2oJXW4hLFwBqWmc&e=2da37782bde14a948336a4458dd26ad3)

Comment: Probably you should use `biblatex + biber` as they understand natively `utf8` encoding, in the place of `natbib` and `multibib`.

Comment: I tried your idea, unfortunately  did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your MWE. I guess you've forgotten to run `bibtex` on `pr` and `en`.

I assume that your original file name is `main`, then you should do like the follwoing:

```
xelatex main 
bibtex main
bibtex pr
bibtex en
xelatex main
xelatex main
```

So you can see the output below:
[image]

P.S. I used `Linux Libertine` font instead of `Times New Roman`, I think this font is more prestigious.